# Need a way to mount or share s3 or any other aws storage service in windows ec2 instance

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We have use case where we want the ability to create shareable drive that would link our ec2 windows instance with any of the storage service (s3 or any other service), such that our user would upload their pdf files in that storage and will be accessible by our windows ec2 instance in which we have program that does pdf files processing. So is there way we can achieve this in aws?

Comment: sounds like an interview question. figure out which AWS service that can provide file sharing to Windows EC2 instance

Comment: Saying you want "any service" is a bit of a wide question. Start by considering _how_ your users would "upload their PDF files" -- are these users staff members, or are they users on the Internet? How do they access your service -- is it via web browser? How are they authenticated? Have you considered stored the files in Amazon S3 and then having your app running on EC2 simply accessing the Amazon S3 service via API calls rather than "mounting" it as a drive? Please tell us more about your end-to-end flow and what _specific_ problem you have.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Our user can be anyone from the internet, and through UI they can upload files . We have pdf preflighting software that run on windows server, and it has the concept of hotfolder which has following component a input folder, output folder, error folder. Whenever a pdf is added in input folder software pick up that pdf file and start processing and if successfull it will added that pdf file in output folder if there is error it generates the error file in xml file. So we need a way to connect user uploaded files and software running on windows ec2 instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Windows software requires a 'local drive' to detect input files, you could mount an Amazon S3 bucket using utilities such as:

- [Cloudberry Drive](https://www.msp360.com/drive.aspx)
- [TntDrive](https://tntdrive.com/mount-amazon-s3-bucket.aspx)
- [Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/)
- [ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com/server/)

Your web application would still be responsible for authenticating users and [Uploading objects using presigned URLs - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) directly to Amazon S3. Your app would also need to determine how to handle the 'output' files so that users can access their converted file.